# Particles に, で for temporal vs spatial location

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-に, particle-で, に-and-で

What does it mean to put で after a temporal expression? I was taught that only に should be used for times but I still see sentences with で sometimes.

This is basically my current understanding:

- Spatial: use に for existential verbs and で otherwise
- Temporal: use に always

This is an example sentence that uses a time+で. How would it be different if it used に?

> 日本では昼間でも夜でもタクシーを拾うことができる。

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is で used as temporal particle. I would read it as でも meaning "either or", "both..." as in ＡでもＢでも.

This applies to all nouns, for example:

> 英語でも日本語でもOKです。
>   English or Japanese, both are OK.

So your sentence could be translated as:

> 日本では昼間でも夜でもタクシーを拾うことができる。
>   Day or night, you can catch a taxi in Japan.

Answer (score 1):

As Szymon says, you have not given an appropriate example: In your sentence でも is being used to give two options but で can be used to indicate when something finishes or a duration:

*-> finishing time:*

> 仕事は５時で終わります。
>   My work finishes at 5pm.

You could also use に but whereas に is a more general particle that gives the time at which an event occurs (ie when work finishes) the で places more emphasis on the time an activity lasts for.

*-> duration:*

> 無色受想行識さんは3日でこのレポートを書いた。
>   無色受想行識 wrote this report in three days.

You have not asked about use of に so I assume you know it is not used with all temporal expresssions　but, for reference, the general rule is that if the time can be specified with a digit then に is used (eg Xmas day is 25 Dec -> クリスマスに）

*Reference: Dictionary of Basic Jpse Grammar*